# SQL multiple join with count

Tags: sql, join, count

I have three tables :

```
FORM(id)

QUESTION(id, form_id, text)  --> X questions for a form

ANSWER(id, question_id, answer_number, text) --> X answers for a question
```

I also have a table for answers given by users :

```
USERS_ANSWERS(id, question_id, answer_number)
```

I would like to have, for each question, the COUNT given by answers, like :

question_id, answer_number, COUNT(users answer for this one)

If there is no answer, then count = 0.

Can you help me ? It takes me hours and I still have nothing. :(

PS : yes I know, why am I not using answer_id in USERS_ANSWERS ? I don't know, it isn't my database...

Comment: Post a little SQL effort. Add a tag with used DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple JOIN should do it;

```
SELECT q.id question_id, a.answer_number, COUNT(ua.id) answer_count
FROM question q
JOIN answer a 
  ON q.id = a.question_id
LEFT JOIN users_answers ua 
  ON q.id = ua.question_id AND a.answer_number = ua.answer_number
GROUP BY q.id, a.answer_number
ORDER BY q.id, a.answer_number
```

The first JOIN combines all questions with their answers to get all valid combinations. The following LEFT JOIN counts all answers for all combinations, allowing zero counts.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1075fe/2).

Answer (score 0):

You simple need to group by (question_id, answer_number) and then count it

```
select 
question_id, answer_number, count(answer_number) as count
from user_answers 
group by question_id, answer_number
order by question_id, answer_number
```

Comment: This will never give count=0 as the question states.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a [sub query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the count from your `USERS_ANSWERS` table for each question and answer record in the other two tables.

Below is an example of doing so, while also returning all questions even if they are unanswered:

```
select qst.id                       as 'question_id',
       isnull(ans.answer_number, 0) as 'answer_number',  -- isnull here because not all questions might have answers
       isnull((select count(1)
                 from USERS_ANSWERS usa
                where usa.question_id   = qst.id
                  and usa.answer_number = ans.answer_number), 0) as 'total user answers'
  from QUESTION qst
         left outer join -- left outer join here because not all questions might have answers
       ANSWER   ans on ans.question_id = qst.id
```